# How to recall a previous command (without execution) in order to change it?

Tags: command-line, terminal, command, command-history, history-expansion

I can't remember the trick where I could get the last command without running it:

let's say I want to be be able to access the command !1255 when pressing the up arrow key and modify the command. So what's the trick to call the command, make it be shown up in the command line but not executed and afterwards accessible via the arrow key up?

I tried with putting an echo, but then I have an echo before the command, I don't remember how to do it correctly.

Comment: if i understand your request properly, perhaps just try a suffix of ":p"   as in "!1255:p"

Comment: @Theophrastus yes, exactly, I had forgotten this :p part and couldn't seem to get the right keywords in google to find it... Thanks guys.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
!1255:p
```

Will do this

`!` is history recall
`1255` is the line number
`:p` prints but does not execute

Then you can use up-arrow to get ther previous (unexecuted) command back and you can change it as you need.

I often combine this with `hg` ("History Grep") - my favorite alias.

```
$ alias hg  # Maybe use hgr instead if you are a Mercurial CLI user.
alias hg='history | tail -200 | grep -i'
```

This searches for text on a recent history line, regardless of case and is used this way:

When I want to search for recent vi commands to edit a certain file and then I want to re-use one of them to edit the same file but with a different file extension.

```
$ hg variables
 6153  vi Variables/user-extensions.js 
 6176  vi Variables/user-extensions.js 
 6178  vi Variables/user-extensions.js 
 6190  vi Variables/user-extensions.js 
 6230  hg variables
$ # Notice the difference in case with V and v is ignored
$ !6190:p
vi Variables/user-extensions.js 
$ ["up-arrow"]
$ vi Variables/user-extensions.[now change .js to .html]
```

I also define `hga` ("History Grep All") to search my entire history:

```
$ alias hga
alias hga='history | grep -i'
```

but I don't use it much because my history is (intentionally) very large and I get too much output that later affects scrolling back thru pages in my terminal.

Comment: Note that `hg` is also [Mercurial's CLI](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TutorialInstall).

Comment: Good note. Added to answer.

Answer (score 12):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> ( Which is the emacs' reverse-incremental-search key binding as @gnp motioned in the comments ) in the terminal allows you to search in the histrory for a specific command. The command will be shown and can be edited before executing. You will see something like this :

[image]

[Source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/08/15-examples-to-master-linux-command-line-history/)

Comment: Thanks! Not really the direct answer to my question, but I didn't know this and I find it really useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also noteworthy,Ctrl+R is emacs' reverse-incremental-search. Many emacs keybindings work accross a lot of GNU tools: Ctrl+A, Ctrl+E, Ctrl+K, Ctrl+Y and others.

Comment: @gnp Thanks for the information, I didn't know that.

Comment: Took me a _long_ time to comfortable with ctrl-r after learning two keys things. 1. ignore the output as you are typing. 2. Be sure you know enough to type enough uniquely for the command you want

Answer (score 8):

In bash `Ctl+alt+e` does shell expansion, thus typing `!1255` and then pressing this combination will substitute current line with the contents of history entry 1255

Comment: didn't do that for me on Ubuntu

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, I just tried in on 14.04 (kubuntu) and it works for me. It is documented in `man bash` as `shell-expand-line`. Maybe there is a shortcut set for gnome-terminal.

Comment: @adonis I never knew this one, thank you very much, indeed it does what I was requesting too. And Indeed I can find more uses from this function. Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

the `fc` command does what you want

`fc -l <number>` will list command history around that number

`fc <number>` will open that command line entry in `vim` (or whatever your default editor is I suppose), so you can edit it, and upon `:wq` it will be available to you with the up arrow.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the fc command while specifying list instead of execute (-l)

```
fc -ln -1
```