# Echo & redirect bash history !commands to file

Tags: command-history, history-expansion

Is it possible to echo and redirect history commands into a script file by the `!` command? Is there variation of the `pipe`, `redirect`, or `tee` commands I am overlooking?

```
  518  xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Return"
  519  xmodmap -e "keycode 23 = Tab"
  535  xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'

[Tech_Ministry@localhost ~]$ echo !535 && !518 >> xmodmap_-e.sh 
echo xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape' && xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Return" >> xmodmap_-e.sh 
xmodmap -e clear Lock -e keycode 0x42 = Escape
```

After reading this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235100/how-to-recall-a-previous-command-without-execution-in-order-to-change-it) I tried `echo !535:p && !518:p >> xmodmap_-e.sh`

I feel as if I am missing something simple.. Is it possible to do this? Possible to echo each command to a separate line?

Answer (score 3):

From `help history`:

```
  -p    perform history expansion on each ARG and display the result
    without storing it in the history list
```

What I usually do is, for example, `history -p \!572 >> myfile` to save command 572 from the history.

For your example, I would use:

```
echo "$(history -p '!535') && $(history -p '!518')" >> xmodmap_-e.sh
```

though there is probably a way to do this with a single `history` command.

(That puts both commands on a single line in the script file, joined with the `&&` operator.)

---

UPDATE: The simpler form I was looking for when I wrote this was:

```
history -p \!535 \!518 >> whatever.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enclose the history marker in double quotes you can capture its expansion as a quoted string:

```
echo "!535 && !518" >> xmodmap_-e.sh
```

---

The reason your published attempt failed is because the `&&` wasn't quoted, so was actioned:

```
echo !535 && !518 >> xmodmap_-e.sh
```

This expanded into the two commands:

```
echo {the expansion of !535}
&&
{run the expansion of !518} >> xmodmap_-e.sh
```

So the first expansion would have been written to *stdout*, and since the `echo` would have succeeded, the second one would have been executed with any of its ensuing output being appended to the file `xmodmap_-e.sh`.